# Можно ли удалить стиль у '<body>' на определнной странице

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

У `<body>` есть бэкграунд, который отсутствует на одной из страниц макета. Можно ли обратиться к этому стилю через CSS или JS обратившись только к html-файлу этой страницы? Или лучше переделать обернув всю верстку контейнером с таким бэком, а на нужной странице прописать доп.класс на удаления бэка?

Answer (score 0):

1. Есть мнение, что правильнее обертывать контейнером, чтобы менять его, а не с body, но работать будет в любом случае.
2. Добавьте класс, к которому обратитесь отдельно.

   `<div class="box box-custom"></div>`

Класс box - общие стили для всех страниц, класс box-custom - для этой страницы.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('body').style.background = "#000000"
```

Ну и можешь любой стиль засунуть
Если удалить хочешь, то можно так:

```
document.querySelector('body').style.removeProperty("background");
```

Comment: Можно просто `document.querySelector('body').style.background = '';`

Comment: я не сил]н в JS, но так понимаю вместо document я должен подставить название документа, но тогда в каком виде?  Например - '$(about.html).query...

Comment: js document'ом сам понимает, что ты что-то делаешь в текущем документе, исправлять не надо ничего, меняй только стили